# React Native - Task '...' uses this output of task '...' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency

Tags: react-native, gradle, build

My teammate has Macbook and I have Windows device. I need to do changes on App. I am facing an Gradle build errors.

**Full error message:**

`Reason: Task ':react-native-vision-camera:generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript' uses this output of task ':react-native-vision-camera:prepareHeaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.`

[image: Error]

I tried to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

to android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml, but it does not worked.

I searched GitHub, Stackoverflow etc. and could not find a solution.